# Wordpress frontpage directs to wrong page

Tags: wordpress, wpml

My website (adventuremenu.ee) was duplicated to our server, but there is one problem. The first page of the website is not loading properly but all the others are. Frontpage is loaded from the other server by JavaScript console which is adventuremenu.cz where it was duplicated to our server.

I am using WPML plugin to translate website to different languages.

Comment: Have you looked at the console (which gives errors)? You can't request http links over HTTPS. `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://adventuremenu.ee/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'XXXX'.`

Comment: Well one of the problem is that our server is https and the website where the page was copied is http, but the fron page shouldn't take data from their server but from ours.